# Understanding Chromium source code structure

Tags: linux

I have download the chromium source code from code.google.com.
I am interested in understanding the receiver application source code.
But by looking at the 1.3GB code, I am not able to actually figure out, which part of the code belongs to receiver side.

Could you please give me some insight on the code structure.
Also the wiki section in code.google.com is empty. I was expecting some documentation there explaining the same.

Answer (score 1):

The [Chromium home page](http://www.chromium.org/Home) has lots of relevant information, especially the [For Developers](http://www.chromium.org/developers) page.

Comment: Thanks James... I was looking only in code.google.com and developers.google.com.. .could not find this link there... I will browse this link and come back with any questions... thanks once again

Comment: Jason... does it include the Chromecast related explanation as well?

Comment: The first hit I get when searching for "chromecast developers" is https://developers.google.com/cast/

Comment: yeah... even i get the same... but i could not find the complete source code of the receive side... which is used in Chromse cast device..

Comment: You can download the javascript for the API at https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/downloads, but just reading the API docs will be a lot easier.  If you're asking about the code on the chromecast itself, who says that's available to look at?

Comment: I am not sure about it... https://code.google.com/p/chromecast-mirrored-source/ ... link specifies that its chromecast open source software... so i assumed that it should be available... or its not?

Comment: No, that just states it is a mirror of "open source software used in Chromecast devices".  Nothing about that states that the Chromecast source itself is open source.